# Parse Android duplicate installations issue

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

When I install the app, parse creates one entry in the installations collections. But when I uninstall the app and install again for same device id, It should not create another entry in installations colection.

Is there something I need to do in the coding to handle this?
For android it is not recording deviceToken value. Is it related to that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually it must create multiple installation entries. Multiple entries in installation table should not create any issue. I would suggest apply a different logic to accomplish your task. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ParseCloud Code to make sure you're never duplicating your user in the *Installation* table. Use ParseCloud.beforesave method in the parse cloud to check for duplication. You can't check for duplication in java code (android) because Parse doesn't allow clients to query the Installation table.

A perfect solution is given by a GitHub User [here](https://gist.github.com/mbmc/ebe5b65bc4eb86904c78).

You will need to have the knowledge of JavaScript to code for the ParseCloud Code (or just copy and paste if it is a one time thing). Also make sure you go through the [ParseCloud Code Docs](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide).